# How to prevent Bootstrap Modal showing on each change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm working on adding conditional logic to some products in our store and showing a Bootstrap modal when a user selects a certain option. I'm new to event bubbling, but have defined select boxes as variables and declared the following code:

```
//All the events I want to listen for:

document.body.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if (event.target !== orientation && event.target !== brightSwitchVol && event.target !== brightSwitchTone && event.target !== potValue && event.target !== switchType) {
      return;
    }
```

I also have a this function to show the modal:

```
function showModal() {
    $("#product-modal").modal("show");
  }
```

I have the modal shown on a few different select boxes when certain options are checked. The modal is "blank" and I dynamically change the text depending on the options. The problem is with my `orientation` select box.

```
 if (orientation.value === "flipped-co") {
      modalHeading.innerHTML = "FLIPPED ORIENTATION NOTE:";
      modalMessage.innerHTML =
        "Please check your existing control cavity to make sure you can use the Flipped Orientation. Some Telecasters have a deeper pocket for the switch, and you cannot reverse the orientation without routing some wood away.";
      showModal();
    }
```

### Problem:

When a user selects `flipped-co` from the `orientation` select box, the modal shows. However, the next item in the event listener list shows the same Flipped Orientation modal content. I believe the problem lies in that the event listener "loops" through each select box and since `flipped-co` is still true, it shows the first modal content, not the next content. How do I prevent this from happening?

I've tried:

`event.stopPropagation()` underneath the orientation code, but that didn't work either.

I've also tried adding a cookie to prevent the modal from showing again after `flipped-co` is selected, but of course that prevents the modal from showing again on the boxes I want it to show for.

[image: Select Boxes with Change Event Listeners]

Comment: The problem is that you are listening to all events at the same time. If you want to show the dialog for specific cases you must register events to each case. In this case, for each select you have created.

Comment: if you are using jquery, you can registar custom events, so you can specify which event must open the specific dialog: https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Comment: The issue is that some of my select box values will disable radio boxes below the select boxs. My goal for this method was to not create an event listener for all 5 of the inputs, but a global event listener that looks for the change event.

Comment: so you can add a class or data attribute for all of them and then add an event listener for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your help. I was able to solve this by adding some additional conditions to my logic. Since the default value of a select box until a user selects an option is `value=""`, I was able to create some logic like:

`if (orientation.value === "flipped-co" && switchType.value === "" && potValue.value === "")`

This does what I want. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Without the possibility to use dataattributes, you could create an array or object that holds the data and check if the selected value exists as a key in that array.

```
var infoModalData = {
  opt1: {
    title: 'Opt 1 Title',
    text: 'Opt 1 Text',
    show: true
  },
  opt2: {
    title: 'Opt 2 Title',
  text: 'Opt 2 Text',
    show: true
  },
  opt3: {
    title: 'Opt 3 Title',
    text: 'Opt 3 Text',
    show: true
  },
};

$('select').on('change', function() {
  let key = $(this).val();
  if(!(key in infoModalData) || !infoModalData[key].show) {
     // this value has no data
     return false;
  }
  let $modal = $( '#myModal' );
  $modal.find('.modal-title').text( infoModalData[key].title );
  $modal.find('.modal-body').text( infoModalData[key].title );
  $modal.modal('show');
  infoModalData[key]. 
});
```

```js
var infoModalData = {
    opt1: {
      title: 'Opt 1 Title',
      text: 'Opt 1 Text',
      show: true
    },
    opt2: {
      title: 'Opt 2 Title',
      text: 'Opt 2 Text',
      show: true
    },
    opt3: {
      title: 'Opt 3 Title',
      text: 'Opt 3 Text',
      show: true
    },
};

$('select').on('change', function() {
 let key = $(this).val();
 if(!(key in infoModalData) || !infoModalData[key].show) {
   // this value has no data
   return false;
  }
  let $modal = $( '#myModal' );
  $modal.find('.modal-title').text( infoModalData[key].title );
  $modal.find('.modal-body').text( infoModalData[key].title );
  $modal.modal('show');
  infoModalData[key].show = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<select class="form-control">
<option value="" disabled selected>please select an option</option>
  <option value="opt1">First opt</option>
  <option value="opt2">Second opt</option>
  <option value="opt3">Third opt</option>
  <option value>No Modal</option>
  <option value>No Modal either</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I wish I could - this is a WooCommerce product and I don't have a lot of ability to customize the selects with data attributes. Why won't `stopPropagation()` work? I thought that after the event was listened to and the modal is shown, `stopPropagation()` would stop listening to the change event on that one select box?

Comment: You can simply move the data-attributes values to an object/array in that case. The key of the object is the value currently selected, if it doesn exist, you dont show the modal, if it does, you fill in the data and show ite.

Comment: `stopPropagation()`stops the event from bubbling up the DOM. If your `<select>` is withing a `<div>` you can not click on the `select` without triggering the click on the `div` also. stopPropagation prevents that.

Comment: I've edited my answer so the modal only shows once.